# Extract data from embedded tableau dashboard

Tags: web-scraping, automation, extract

I’m trying to extract data from this state website: https://www.mass.gov/info-details/interactive-beach-water-quality-dashboard

But they have everything embedded in tableau. Additionally, for the excel download link provided, it fails to include the filename (I’m assuming it renders a token at the time of clicking and determines the filename to use): https://www.mass.gov/doc/beach-dashboard-data/download

Are there any workarounds to programmatically extracting data from this site or am I SOL?

A website with scrapable or otherwise extractable content. No published API available.